# How can one derive the circumference of a circle using integrals?

Tags: integration, circles, proof-explanation

Many proofs for the area of a circle start with something like

$$ A(r) = \int_0^r 2 \pi t dt $$

such as at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area_of_a_disk#Onion_proof , but I don't understand how to get to this starting point.

Using the same notation at the wikipedia article, we can imagine the radial line made up of many infintesimally small fragments $h$ each at a distance $t$ from the center of the circle. Considering just one of these fragments, the area swept out by this fragment around the circle (i.e., the circumferential line length) is

$$ L = \int_0^{2\pi} ([t+h]-t) d \theta = \int_0^{2\pi} h d \theta = 2 \pi h$$

But obviously the circumference of a line should be $2 \pi t$.

I see that there are various ways to derive this, but I'm specifically trying to understand where my logic is wrong in applying this method of reasoning. I realize this is an elementary question, but I appreciate any kind help.

Thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't be considering a small change of length $h$ unless you plan to sum up infinitely many of them, and I do not see any sums here

Comment: @ASKASK If h is infinitesimally small, isn't the "height" of the area effectively small enough that I have a line? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: What do you think you are measuring the "height" of?

Comment: @ASKASK The height `h` is the height of the infinitesimally small piece of the radial line. It seems to me that “infinitesimally small” can be the height of a circumferential line (i.e., essentially zero). But are you saying this cannot be the case? Is it possible to mathematically explain why not?

Comment: @Strugglingsnowman I think it would be helpful if you could add a sketch to your question, showing what you mean by "height of the infinitesimally small piece of the radial line", what $t$ is, etc.  In particular it's not clear what the expression $[(t+h)-t]$ refers to geometrically.

Answer (score 4):

One begins reasoning this way:  A circle (actually, you mean a *disk*) is radially symmetric, i.e., the same shape in every direction from its center.  (A square or an oval is *not* radially symmetric.)  Thus you reason that the only variable that changes is in the radial direction, not the angular direction.  You then reason that the radially-symmetric shapes that can "cover" the disk are rings of different radii.  To cover the entire disk you sum up an infinite number of these rings.

The area of the black ring is $2 \pi t\ dt$.  You add those up, from $t = 0$ to $t = r$.
[image]

If this reasoning isn't clear, I urge you to speak to your teacher.

Comment: I think this misses the point of my question, since I state in the first sentence that I'm trying to understand how to get to such a starting point based on my aforementioned logic. Or maybe, since it already has 3 upvotes, I'm missing something about this answer?

Comment: How far back would you accept a "starting point"?  After all, you were not clear on the difference between a circle and a disk.  Do we have start way way back there?

Comment: The OP was asking for circumference and the answer is for circle area? The result of the integral should be 2r